# Parsing multiple JSON objects in Go

Tags: json, go

Objects like the below can be parsed quite easily using the `encoding/json` package.

```
[ 
    {"something":"foo"},
    {"something-else":"bar"}
]
```

The trouble I am facing is when there are multiple dicts returned from the server like this :

```
{"something":"foo"}
{"something-else":"bar"}
```

This can't be parsed using the code below.

```
correct_format := strings.Replace(string(resp_body), "}{", "},{", -1)
json_output := "[" + correct_format + "]"
```

I am trying to parse Common Crawl data (see [example](http://index.commoncrawl.org/CC-MAIN-2018-17-index?url=*.netflix.com&output=json)).

How can I do this?

Comment: It is not a valid json that's the reason first convert it into valid json and then parse it.

Comment: That JSON cannot be parsed at all, let alone easily, because it's invalid.

Comment: Json is not invalid. Each line contains a separate Json object actually.

Comment: Note that the document at the URL in the question contains a text file with [line-delimited JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming#Line-delimited_JSON) (i.e. one JSON document per line).

Comment: Sorry, by mistake i posted wrong json

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming your input is really a series of valid JSON documents, use a [json.Decoder](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder) to decode them:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

var input = `
{"foo": "bar"}
{"foo": "baz"}
`

type Doc struct {
    Foo string
}

func main() {
    dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(input))
    for {
        var doc Doc

        err := dec.Decode(&doc)
        if err == io.EOF {
            // all done
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", doc)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ANx8MoMC0yq

If your input really is what you've shown in the question, that's not JSON and you have to write your own parser.

Comment: This is a great solution because it works both for one object per line, and for formatted streams. that the check on `io.EOF` can be eliminated by using `json.Decoder.More()`. https://go.dev/play/p/Ouo7xlDV6iy

Comment: More is intended to be used with the Token interface of the decoder. When used with newline delimited JSON it silently accepts certain types of malformed inputs: https://go.dev/play/p/ync4g9OuTrq

Answer (score 2):

Seems like each line is its own json object.

You may get away with the following code which will structure this output into correct json:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    base := `{"trolo":"lolo"}
{"trolo2":"lolo2"}`

    delimited := strings.Replace(base, "\n", ",", -1)

    final := "[" + delimited + "]"
    fmt.Println(final)
}
```

You should be able to use `encoding/json` library on `final` now.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to parse each incoming line, line by line, and then add each one to a collection in code (ie a slice)  Go provides a line [scanner](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner) for this.

```
yourCollection := []yourObject{}
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(YOUR_SOURCE)
for scanner.Scan() {
    obj, err := PARSE_JSON_INTO_yourObject(scanner.Text())
    if err != nil {
       // something
    }
    yourCollection = append(yourCollection, obj)
}
if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading standard input:", err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the ndjson from the file row by row and parse it then apply the logical operations on it. In the below sample instead of reading from the file, I have used an Array of JSON string.

```golang
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type NestedObject struct {
    D string
    E string
}

type OuterObject struct {
    A string
    B string
    C []NestedObject
}

func main() {

    myJsonString := []string{`{"A":"1","B":"2","C":[{"D":"100","E":"10"}]}`, `{"A":"11","B":"21","C":[{"D":"1001","E":"101"}]}`}
    for index, each := range myJsonString {
        fmt.Printf("Index value [%d] is [%v]\n", index, each)
        var obj OuterObject
        json.Unmarshal([]byte(each), &obj)
        fmt.Printf("a: %v, b: %v, c: %v", obj.A, obj.B, obj.C)
        fmt.Println()
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Index value [0] is [{"A":"1","B":"2","C":[{"D":"100","E":"10"}]}]
a: 1, b: 2, c: [{100 10}]
Index value [1] is [{"A":"11","B":"21","C":[{"D":"1001","E":"101"}]}]
a: 11, b: 21, c: [{1001 101}]
```

[Try it on golang play](https://play.golang.org/p/JmhsEqHmIYb)