# How to parse a JSON string returned from scanner.Text()

Tags: go, unmarshalling

I'm new to Golang and a lot of concepts are new for me. My goal is the following:

I have a file which is located in the cloud storage. I want to read it line by line and while getting a new line parse it and work with the data from it. So suppose my file looks like this:

```
{
 "data":[{
  "id":"1",
  "type":"type",
  "attributes":{
    "title":"Title",
    "url":"URL",
    "description":"Description"
  }
 }]
}
{
 "data":[{
  "id":"2",
  "type":"type2",
  "attributes":{
    "title":"Title2",
    "url":"URL2",
    "description":"Description2"
  }
 }]
}
```

Now, in my project I have the following code:

```
//Structs 
type JA struct {
    Title       string `json:"title"`
    Url         string `json:"url"`
    Description string `json:"description"`
}

type JData struct {
    Id         string `json:"id"`
    Attributes JA     `json:"attributes"`
}

type JD struct {
    Data JData `json:"data"`
}

//gets info from the db
rc, err := client.Bucket(bucket).Object(object).NewReader(ctx)

for scanner.Scan() {
    job := JD{}

    jobData := scanner.Text()
    fmt.Println(jobData[0])
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jobData), &job)
    fmt.Println(job)
}
```

The last line gives me the following output - {{ {  }}} and I don't understand why; also, if I try to output jobData, I get a json line with proper text, but if I try to output jobData[0], I just get a set of numbers (123). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. NEVER ignore errors. 2. A scanner is the wrong tool for reading JSON.

Comment: Is your data encoded as newline-delimited JSON? If yes, then it appears that each line of the data from the JSON snippet in your question, considered individually, is not valid a JSON value.

Comment: @Volker which one is right then? How should I go about it?

Comment: @nishanthshanmugham I am not sure but I ran a function to test whether it was json and it showed me that it was...

Comment: You have a stream of JSON documents.  The [decoder example in the documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#example-Decoder) shows how to decode a stream of JSON documents.

Comment: @MikhailLadonkin: You can use the code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50352805/3309046.

Comment: And as a comment says above, remember to check the error for the Cloud Storage call.

Comment: It bears repeating: *never* ignore errors.  If you do, you'll be staring at your code trying to debug something and it will be some silly condition like a misspelling, well explained in an error you're ignoring.  Error handling is *part* of the algorithm.