# Handling streamed HTTP ressponses

Tags: go, http, stream

I have the following example that connects to an HTTP service which streams responses back in a stream of chunks to create a JSON structure. For each chunk my code appends a byte `rb` array with the individual lines. However, my problem is trying to work out when the `rb` is complete so I can then decode it.

Am I missing something obvious here ?

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    body := []byte("test")

    resp, err := http.Post("http://localhost:8281/tap", "application/json", bytes.NewReader(body))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    fmt.Printf("Status: [%s]\n", resp.Status)
    fmt.Println()
    //var rb []byte
    reader := bufio.NewReader(resp.Body)
    var rb []byte

    for {

        line, err := reader.ReadBytes('\n')
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            fmt.Printf("Error reading streamed bytes %v", err)
        }
        rb = append(rb, line...)

        fmt.Println(rb)

    }
}
```

Comment: You're asking this for the third day now, and we keep telling you to [use a json.Decoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50350010/parsing-multiple-json-objects-in-go). Why doesn't that work for you?

Comment: HTTP/1 or HTTP/1.1 connections cannot be streamed, only if you are working with http/2 which is not the case

Comment: I think that you are meaning other thing with stream response

Comment: Yes my problem was understanding how to deal with stream responses. I have it working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the bugs in the program, `rb` is complete after the loop breaks.

The program does have bugs:

- The program only breaks out of the loop on EOF. The program will spin forever on any other kind of error.
- The program does not handle the case where ReadBytes returns data and an error.  An example of where this can happen is when the response does not end with the delimiter.

It looks like your goal is to slurp up the entire response to `rb`.  Use [io.ReadAll](https://godoc.org/io#ReadAll) do do that:

```
resp, err := http.Post("http://localhost:8281/tap", "application/json", bytes.NewReader(body))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)
    return
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
rb, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
var data SomeType
err = json.Unmarshal(rb, &data)
if err != nil {
     // handle error
}
```

If you want to decode the response body as JSON, then a better approach is to let the JSON [decoder](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Decoder) read the response body:

```
resp, err := http.Post("http://localhost:8281/tap", "application/json", bytes.NewReader(body))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)
    return
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
var data SomeType
err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&data)
```

Comment: Thank for taking the time to explain. Now I understand. Comments like just use xxxx from OP doesn't help.